# Extract xml files from a zip in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to extract xml files from one zip file using python. I would like to extract the content of each xml and save it in some python structure.

I am building a text classifier and I would like to be able to view the files separately so I can process them.

I am using Jupyter notebook, so the zip file is located in the same location as my code file.

I tried the below

```
#unizipping the file
data = zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip', 'r')

#iterating through the names of the files to open them
for name in data.namelist():
#open the xml files and save them to a txt file
       with data.open(name) as inputFile, open('tweet.txt','w') as outputFile:
                for line in inputFile:
                    newLine=line.strip()
                    outputFile.write(newLine)
```

But I get an error message

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Sample of the xml files

```
<author lang="en">
    <documents>
        <document><![CDATA[@Michael_J_Parry can't comment on the transphobic but the feminist girl in me is a bit gut reaction offended]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[@NZStuff and to make it worse you put a pic of the sisters holding trophies onto the hotel story... hoping this was accident, guessing not]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[@NZStuff Serena wins 23rd title &amp; you lead with a hotel bill Tennis Auck has no qualms with, burying the story of her record breaking win]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[Tietjens is now coaching Samoa!! I might be a little slow to pick up on this, sorry. But how awesome is that.]]></document>
    </documents>
</author>
```

Any tip on how to approach this would be useful. Thank you

Comment: You have to parse out the data from the `<document>` tag first and than you can read it

Comment: Check out this link :https://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/